# What about copy-paste from Wikipedia?

Tags: discussion

*Note: I'm seriously biased; I'm not a WP fan. Many errors, badly written lemmas, trivialities.*

This is the current tag wiki excerpt for the [555](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/555):

> "The 555 timer IC is an integrated circuit (chip) used in a variety of timer, pulse generation and oscillator applications. The part is still in widespread use, thanks to its ease of use, low price and good stability. As of 2003, it is estimated that 1 billion units are manufactured every year. - Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC)"

Copy-paste from Wikipedia. Many other wikis also refer to Wikipedia for further information. Doesn't that make our wikis superfluous? Or even the whole EE site? You can find anything on Wikipedia. If as I understand it EE wants to be self-sustained, then why rely on others?

Comment: Unlike links to other sites, Wikipedia is unlikely to go away.

Comment: @stevenvh, Wikipedia does use the same IP rules that our site does, if you quote them you must cite your source, that is why the links exist right there.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with copying from Wikipedia as long as one gives credit and a link to the original article. The question should be more about *the quality and usability* of the actual text that is copied. Wikipedia articles tend to get long and longer, filled with a lot of information. A good tag wiki should only contain the most relevant parts and link to Wikipedia (and other resources) for further information

Answer (score 2):

Most ICs don't have a Wikipedia entry.  So for one that does, like the 555, it's good to have the link to denote its historical significance.

Answer (score 2):

> Copy-paste from Wikipedia. Many other wikis also refer to Wikipedia for further information. Doesn't that make our wikis superfluous?

The wiki has to start somewhere. Ideally someone, preferably an expert on that tag, will write the tag wiki. But if a user whom does not feel like a sure expert, or feels wikipedia has already done the job can source it from wikipediate and cite them. Is this an okay place to get information, yes.

> Or even the whole EE site? You can find anything on Wikipedia. If as I understand it EE wants to be self-sustained, then why rely on others?

Honestly, this seems a bit melodramatic to me when reading, which I doubt was your intent. Does using external sources make our site superfluous? No, using sources for material is standard. When a paper is published you cite papers that were your source for ideas or further reading, the same is true here.

Tag wiki's are somewhat different. Ideally they give some baseline about the subject and direct someone to basic reading they can do if they want to learn more about the subject before they start writing questions. Answers should be self contained but it does not make sense to expect a wiki not to give further reading, if we have a really detailed question on that subject it should definitely be referenced. The main point here is that there are questions too simple and those questions might be avoided just by sending someone to the wiki before they ask about that subject, we can hope.

Answer (score 1):

The danger of copying from another site (like eg. Wikipedia) is that the original article may be updated or corrected and the copy on EE won't. For this reason it is bad practice to store an article in two (or more) places.

I think that although it is allowed to copy (when source cited), I'd rather see original wording. This also allows one to read another view on a same or similar topic, with different wording. Many people (like myself) don't have English as first language and it may be very valuable to read about the same topic in different wording.

Of course just copying a link into the wiki won't give you any reputation or cool badges.

Comment: Helemaal mee eens. I mean, agreed ;-)